# LINQ to Entities for SQL Server and Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linq-to-entities

Can I write the same queries (select, insert, update etc.) in LINQ to Entites that will be validate for SQL SERVER and Oracle database?

I thinking that if I write now query for SQL SERVER, it will be ok for future Oracle db...?

It's exist pattern which provide interface for something like that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ to entities is [completely isolated from your data access layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx) and deals only with object services.

The actual database access is handled at a lower layer.

Comment: Can You explain me what is object services? I only know that I query with LINQ to my Entity Data Model of my db, and all my knowledge about my data layer is it :/

Comment: @netmajor - Have a look at the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386871.aspx - it's a common set of services that all entities provide.